# Wear OS permissions in the official documentation

Tags: android, android-permissions, wear-os

I’m currently developing a Wear OS app (version 3), and I’m trying to figure out what permissions I need to request in my manifest file.

Other than the Android permissions [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) that mentions Wear OS a couple of times, does anyone know if there is a list of specific Wear OS permissions available in the Android documentation?

Comment: The permissions that you need to declare in your manifest file is completely dependent on the functionality of your application. By default, you don't have to declare any. If you read through the documentation for specific features or functionality (e.g. recording audio, keeping the screen on) it will typically explicitly call out the permission required to perform this task.

What you DO need to make sure you have in your manifest file is the following: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />